# Any way to match a pattern EITHER preceded OR followed by a certain character?

Tags: javascript, regex

For instance, I'd like to match all of the following strings:

'abc'
'cba'
'bca'
'cab'
'racb'
'rcab'
'bacr'

but NOT any of the following:

'rabcr'
'rbacr'
'rbcar'

Is this possible with regex?

Comment: so you want to match strings that don't begin and end with the same letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
/^(?:[abc]{3}r?|r[abc]{3})$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of string
(?:       # Non-capturing group:
 [abc]{3} # Either match abc,cba,bac etc.
 r?       # optionally followed by r
|         # or
 r        # match r
 [abc]{3} # followed by abc,cba,bac etc.
)         # End of group
$         # End of string
```

Some regex engines support [conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), but JavaScript is not among them. But in .NET, you could do

```
^(r)?[abc]{3}(?(1)|r?)$
```

without the need to write your character class twice in the same regex.

**Explanation:**

```
^        # Start of string
(r)?     # Match r in group 1, but make the group optional
[abc]{3} # Match abc,cab etc.
(?(1)    # If group 1 participated in the match,
         # then match nothing,
|        # else
 r?      # match r (or nothing)
)        # End of conditional
$        # End of string
```

Another solution in JavaScript would be to use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?:r(?!.*r$))?[abc]{3}r?$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of string
(?:       # Non-capturing group:
 r        # Match r
 (?!.*r$) # only if the string doesn't end in r
)?        # Make the group optional
[abc]{3}  # Match abc etc.
r?        # Match r (optionally)
$         # End of string
```

Comment: Thanks, that last solution is nice, and what I was looking for... that is, not needing to repeat myself.